# Finding a prime number using recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing this problem for school and I have some issues with it. I can't get it to actually calculate the prime number. Obviously, when I run a test from main with the number 4 it says 4 is a prime number when we all know it's not. How do I need to write out the equation?

The instructions are as follows.

Use RECURSION to write this function (or make this function a wrapper over another recursive function)

```
 * a number is prime if it is divisible only by itself and 1 
 * (that is, if it is not divisible by any number between * itself and 1; 
 * we can optimize and just check between 2 and the square root of the number).
 * by convention, 1 is NOT prime
 * this function returns true if its parameter is prime, false otherwise.
 * One way to do this is to test all numbers between 2 and n; if any of them     
 * divides it, then it is not prime. If you reach the end, then it is.
 * Examples:
 * isPrime(1) => false
 * isPrime(2) => true
 * isPrime(3) => true
 * isPrime(4) => false
 */



public static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) { 
        return false; 
    } if (n == 2 || n == 3) { 
        return true; 
    } if (Math.sqrt(n) % 2 == 0) { 
        return true;
    }else
        return isPrime(n);
    }
```

The below code is from the grader.java that my prof uses to grade the program. There are a few calls to the isprime method. It always seems to get hung up on 4 (I see why... 4 squared % 2 == 0) and 4 isn't  a prime #.

```
         public void testIsPrime()
{
    Assert.assertEquals("1 is not prime", false,Assignment4.isPrime(1));
    Assert.assertEquals("2 is prime", true,Assignment4.isPrime(3));
    Assert.assertEquals("4 is not prime", false,Assignment4.isPrime(4));
    Assert.assertEquals("7 is prime", true,Assignment4.isPrime(7));
    Assert.assertEquals("9 is not prime", false,Assignment4.isPrime(9));
    Assert.assertEquals("35 is not prime", false,Assignment4.isPrime(35));
    Assert.assertEquals("37 is prime", true,Assignment4.isPrime(37));        
}
```

Comment: My bad. Edited.

Comment: Have you ever written any working recursive code?

Comment: I've just started this past week. I'm still learning and often make mistakes. Just trying to get some feedback on what I'm doing right/wrong. Thanks.

Comment: It is not necessary to use recursion in this case since it only once will execute the block of instructions isPrime method as last number as parameter value never changes always get the same result.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Perhaps a loop would be even better. I was just trying to follow the instructions. (See edited question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment is giving you a vital hint:

> or make this function a wrapper over another recursive function

```
public static boolean isPrime_helper(int number, int divisor)
{
    /* write code to return true if divisor is > square root of number */
    /* which can also be expressed divisor squared is > number */

    /* write code here to test if divisor divides number without remainder */
    /* and return false if it does.  Otherwise: */

    return isPrime_helper(number, divisor + 2);
}

public static boolean isPrime(int number)
{
    /* deal with the special cases 2, < 2, and even numbers here */
    /* Otherwise: */

    return isPrime_helper(number, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*cdlane*'s answer has the basic correction.  I just want to make sure that you know where your try doesn't work.  You have two fatal problems:

1. You have no simplification in your recursion.  If you haven't hit the base cases (0-3), you recur with the *same* number, throwing you into an infinite loop.
2. Your **sqrt** clause is both needless and wrong.  If the sqrt of a number is even, it *cannot* be prime.  Is this supposed to be a test for stopping the recursion?

Answer (score -3):

In Prime numbers, 2 can't be prime because you can divide it by 2 and it shouldn't be able to divide by 2. Hence, if `number%2` is 0 or number is 2 you need to return false.

When a number is not 2 or it's not possible to divide it by 0, you can check for other numbers with a for loop inside your function.

Take a look at following code it helps you to understand what's going on:

```
public boolean isPrime (int number){
    if ((number%2)==0 && number != 2) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        for (int i =3; i*i<number; i++ )
        {
            if (number%i ==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```